# rich link preview in android

Tags: python, android, android-layout, android-studio, android-webview

I am working on an application where I think rich link preview (whatsapp supports it,refer image) will be helpful for users but I am not able to get an idea to  start on it.Any kind of suggestion/hint on how to do this will be helpful.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**
here is the latest solution

```
implementation 'io.github.ponnamkarthik:richlinkpreview:1.0.9'
```

in your XML

```
<io.github.ponnamkarthik.richlinkpreview.RichLinkView
    android:id="@+id/richLinkView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</io.github.ponnamkarthik.richlinkpreview.RichLinkView>
```

in java :

```
richLinkView = (RichLinkView) findViewById(R.id.richLinkView);
        
        
        
        richLinkView.setLink("https://stackoverflow.com", new ViewListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(boolean status) {
                
            }
            
            @Override
            public void onError(Exception e) {
                
            }
        });
```

***For more styles visit***

[Library on GitHub](https://github.com/ponnamkarthik/RichLinkPreview)

**Old Answer**

You can use this [Android Link Preview](https://github.com/LeonardoCardoso/Android-Link-Preview) library on github. for that just add the repository to your build.gradle file like this

```
repositories {
jcenter()
maven { url 'https://github.com/leonardocardoso/mvn-repo/raw/master/maven-deploy'}
     }
```

And you can use the artifacts like this:

```
dependencies {
compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3' // required
compile 'com.leocardz:link-preview:1.2.1@aar'

}
```

you can download a sample application from [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.leocardz.link.preview&feature=search_result)

Comment: Link is fixed please check

Comment: it is not properly working when we used it in recycler view, the preview images are wrongly showing in the recycler view items.

Comment: @Madhan can you show us how you implemented in the recycler view... as an answer to this question maybe

Comment: @Madhan please ask another question

Comment: @DigvijaySingh This library is no more compatible with the android studio, any solution?

Comment: This library does not work anymore! Can't even add it to dependency!

Answer (score 4):

I am late in the party, but I have found new lib which provide easy to integrate and default preview style, i.e WhatsApp, Skype, Telegram etc...

> implementation ‘io.github.ponnamkarthik:richlinkpreview:1.0.9’

[Link Preview lib integration step by step](https://medium.com/@hiteshdhamshaniya.wvmagic/how-to-get-link-preview-in-your-android-application-c8c6d332f137)

Please check easy implementation from above link

Comment: Its work for me for youtube URL as well, Can you please check the medium post example, if still not get, if you can provide youtube URL I can check the issue

Comment: that worked for me as well, I wasn't using latest jsoup version, so that was not working. After I updated jsoup version it started working.

Comment: @Hitesh It doesn't provide data of Twitter and Facebook links. Any solution for that?

Comment: @ShahoodulHassan Did you get twitter icon in the preview, I can see the Twitter icon when I tried to get the preview form any tweet...
The issue is already registered in lib
https://github.com/PonnamKarthik/RichLinkPreview/issues/10

Comment: @ShahoodulHassan hi, have you found any solution for how to get preview from twitter link?

Answer (score 2):

I found this library, I didn't try it but hope will work for you 
https://github.com/FreesoulApps/PreviewAndroid

Answer (score 1):

I just tried and implement the **Rich Link Preview** feature into my app through [URLEmbeddedView](https://github.com/nguyencse/URLEmbeddedView) and it was working perfectly fine. Before that, i tried to implement almost all solutions but failed because mostly are outdated and do not support on the  latest android API levels. Let me know if anyone is facing issue